# How to write this equation that runs partitions?

Tags: matlab

I don't know where to go with this. I think I have the right stuff down but I don't understand.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmoU9.jpg

It keeps running the loop forever and I don't know why.

```
n=9; 
r =0; 
p = 0;
syms x 

v=1.7;

while abs(v-r) > 10^(-5)

    n=n+1;
    r = 0;
    a = 0;
    b= 1/n;

    for i = 1:n

    r = r + exp(((i+1)+exp(i))/2)*(b-a)
    end


    ['done']
end
```

The output should be 85. But I'm getting like a couple thousand. I have tried changing the equation in the for loop but I do not know why it is giving me symbolic errors.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with the posted code:

1. The parentheses are misaligned in the r=r + ... statement
2. Instead of exp(i) and exp(i+1), you should use exp(b*i) and exp(b*(i+1)) in order to account for the given spacing.
3. Your value of "v" which is supposed be the exact answer should equal e-1, which is 1.71828. Using the approximate 1.7 is going to be very problematic when you are trying to converge to the exact solution within 5 decimal places.
4. Your for loop should go from 0 to n-1, this way you don't add up any values past your integral range.

```
n=9; 
r =0; 
p = 0;
v=e-1;

while abs(v-r) > 10^(-5)

    n=n+1;
    r = 0;
    a = 0;
    b= 1/n;

    for i = 0:n-1
      r = r + ((exp(b*(i+1))+exp(b*i))/2)*(b-a);
    end
end
```